master bedroom with open toilet and bath
i have a master bedroom in which there is an opening to access toilet and bathroom but we dont have a door (i mean a door to open\close).The opening is without door.
I would like to know if it is permissible in islam.

Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. And we'd like to know what makes you think it couldn't be permissible... elaborate your question please and read [ask].
